# Add horizontal cells based on a criteria set in a specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

`=SUMIFS(F3:O3, E3:E12,"Santander")`

I need a formula that adds up the value of columns e.g. F3:O3 only if the criteria in cell E3 says "Santander". It's for bank reconciliation purposes whereby when I enter an expense on a line and assign it a criteria then it will be added to the bank balance at the end of each row where applicable. I've had a good hunt through the blogs haven't found anything that works yet.

Comment: Adding cells based on values in other cells is a common question here. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

#### IF Function

The [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) allows you to make logical comparisons between a value and what you expect. It can have two results. The first result is if your comparison is **TRUE**, and the second is if your comparison is **FALSE**.

```
# If TRUE:  SUM(F3:O3)
# If FALSE: "" (blank)
  
=IF(E3="Santander", SUM(F3:O3), "")
```

<sub>**Example: TRUE**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Example: FALSE**</sub>
[image]